# Array index out of bounds error when using "."

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to get this bit of code to work when getting someones date of birth and having to split it up in dd/mm/yyyy and using "." as the thing that separates day from month and month from year. I managed to get it to work for other characters such as "/", " ", "-". When i try to use "." i get an array index out of bounds exception error.

```
if(input.contains("."))
{
String[] tokens = input.split(".");
day = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
intMonth = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
year = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
}
```

Variables are declared above correctly (Well i assume so). As they work with other cases.
If not clear feel free to ask any questions, and thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of `input`?

Comment: if input is just a . then tokens' size will be 0.So It will give ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception.

Comment: Its my scanner, 
    Scanner input = Scanner(System.in);

Answer (score 8, accepted):

String.split in java uses the input string as a regular expression. In regular expressions, a period matches any character, so that will split on every character in the string. To do what you want you would want to split on `"\\."` which would escape the period in the regular expression, so that it would only split on a period character, not any character.

Comment: That stops the error, thanks :)
It then enters my switch statement, but instead of returning the correct month as per user input, it goes to default case.

Comment: Any idea with the switch statement?

Comment: There's not enough information. I would have to see the switch statement and the input being used.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the `.` character. Change this:

```
String[] tokens = input.split(".");
```

to

```
String[] tokens = input.split("\\.");
```

Answer (score 2):

`String.split()` takes a regex as parameter and `.` (dot) is a reserved char; you need to escape it in this manner `input.split("\\.");`.
Using a `new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").parse(input)` will be more robust and easy

Answer (score 1):

use

```
input.split("\\.")
```

instead

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
if(input.contains("."))
{
String[] tokens = input.split("\\.");
day = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
intMonth = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
year = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
}
```

Comment: That returns another error, Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 3

Answer (score 0):

Your code just checks that at least one period character is in `input`, but you don't verify that you have a whole `dd.mm.yyyy` date. Generally, whenever you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, it's a good idea to set a breakpoint on the line before the exception and manually inspect the array's contents; it'll frequently reveal some mismatch you didn't anticipate.

Is there a reason you're not just using `DateFormat`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about input ? because it may just be ".", resulting in an array of a shorter length. Also use `\\.` to match for a `.`.

```
  String[] tokens = input.split("\\.");
  day      = token.length > 0 ? Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]) : 0;
  month    = token.length > 1 ? Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]) : 0;
  year     = token.length > 2 ? Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]) : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good option to check the javadoc, see [String#split(String regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29). As others have pointed out, String#split takes an regular expression. Read up on regex [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum).